# How can I supply a path parameter to the displayed path in SwaggerUi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle, api-versioning

I have setup Swagger/Swashbuckle on my WebAPI project. I have followed the [guide from Microsoft](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/API-Documentation) which covers how to setup Aspnet.WebApi.Versioning with Swagger. My API has multiple versions, so there is a `{version}` parameter set in the route attributes, like this:

```
[ApiVersion("2")]
[RoutePrefix("api/{version:apiVersion}/values")]
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    [Route("UserInfo")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

My issue is that this shows a `{version}` attribute in the path shown in the docs, like this:

[image]

Instead I want this path attribute to actually have the value in the `ApiVersion` attribute, so that there can be no confusion for the clients who read the documentation. Ideally, given that the UrlDiscoverySelector is set to `v2` the paths above should be:

```
/api/2/account/userinfo
/api/2/account/externallogin
/api/2/account/manageinfo
```

My attempts to simply replace the `{version}` in the `RelativePath` of the `ApiExplorer` worked in the UI, but broke the test functionality as `{version}` was changed to a `query` parameter instead of a `path`, which is not how my API is configured.

Is it possible I can amend the values in the `ApiExplorer` before swagger builds the documentation while still retaining test functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API Explorer for API versioning now supports the behavior out-of-the-box using:

```
options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true
```

This will do the substitution work for you and removes the API version parameter from the action descriptor. You generally don't need to change the default format applied to the substituted value, but you can change it using:

```
options.SubstitutionFormat = "VVV"; // this is the default
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Swashbuckle and used a Document filter

```
public class VersionedOperationsFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        foreach (var apiDescriptionsGroup in context.ApiDescriptionsGroups.Items)
        {
            var version = apiDescriptionsGroup.GroupName;
            foreach (ApiDescription apiDescription in apiDescriptionsGroup.Items)
            {
                apiDescription.RelativePath = apiDescription.RelativePath.Replace("{version}", version);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs add this filter:

```
services.AddMvc();
        var defaultApiVer = new ApiVersion(1, 0);


        services.AddApiVersioning(option =>
        {
            option.ReportApiVersions = true;
            option.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
            option.DefaultApiVersion = defaultApiVer;
        });

        services.AddMvcCore().AddVersionedApiExplorer(e=>e.DefaultApiVersion = defaultApiVer);

        services.AddSwaggerGen(
            options =>
            {
                var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IApiVersionDescriptionProvider>();
                options.DocumentFilter<VersionedOperationsFilter>();

                //// add a swagger document for each discovered API version
                //// note: you might choose to skip or document deprecated API versions differently
                foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
                {
                        options.SwaggerDoc(description.GroupName.ToString(),
                            CreateInfoForApiVersion(description));
                }

                //// integrate xml comments
                options.IncludeXmlComments(Path.ChangeExtension(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location, "xml"));

            });
```

[end result in Swagger UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeZNL.png)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and apologies for the late response as I've only just got around to looking at this again. Your code looks ideal, however the signature you're using for the `IDocumentFilter` doesn't match the version of Seashbuckle I'm using. It instead expects `Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, IApiExplorer apiExplorer)` - note that I'm working on a WebApi project, not an MVC one, should it make a difference

Comment: The thing is that I'm using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore version so it has a different signature but principle should be the same - like [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/master/Swashbuckle.Dummy.Core/SwaggerExtensions/AppendVersionToBasePath.cs#L14)